# CentOS/Nginx server isn't working, hosting Node apps

Tags: linux, apache, nginx, centos, vps

I have a pretty simple server setup that isn't working for some reason.

I have two apps running locally, one on port `1999` and the other on port `8000`.

I have disabled Apache, and have `nginx` installed. Here's my `nginx.conf` in `/etc/nginx/`:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  8;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include   /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip  on;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

And here's my `default.conf` in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/` :

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name attendahh.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:1999;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;

    server_name threadfinder.net;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Navigating to `http://my-ip-address:1999` and `http://my-ip-address:8000` works just fine, but going to my domains does not.

I get the feeling that `NGINX` just plain isn't working, and maybe something in my hosts file/something else is messing things up. Any ideas on what steps I can take to work this out? This is a fresh install of `NGINX`.

**EDIT: Also, when I try to access `threadfinder.net` and `attendahh.com` nothing appears in my access logs at `/var/log/nginx/access.log`**

Answer (score 1):

Well, do you have problem with DNS?

Comment: It's quite possible, looking into this now.

Comment: The nameservers seem to be setup properly, doing `dig @23.226.227.16 attendahh.com` works (as far as I know?). Any further tests I can do to see what's up?